# PhP foreach through class instances

Tags: php, object, foreach

I'm wondering about this weird thing:

```
public function getAllCustomers()
{
    $customers = $this->redis->keys("customer:*");
    foreach ($customers as $value) {
        return new \Customer($this->redis->hget($value,"name"),$this->redis->hget($value,"id"),$this->redis->hget($value,"email"));
    }
}
```

This method returns all customers from my database.

But if I try to loop through all of these customers:

```
foreach ($customerController->getAllCustomers() as $customer) {
    var_dump($customer);
}
```

The `getName()` method is not found. var_dump returns:

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Customer class:

```
class Customer {
    var $name;
    var $id;
    var $email;

    function __construct($name, $id,$email) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

     /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
    */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
       return "";
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to `PHP` and don't understand why I can't access the Customer object's field.

Comment: Can you please add `var_dump` or `print_r` on the `$customer` in your for-loop?

Comment: You are returning INSIDE a foreach loop. So that loop will run only once

Comment: And you are returning an Array and NOT an Object

Comment: `return array(\Customer(...` - are you also missing a `new` here? The code you've posted should just cause a syntax error.

Comment: var_dump returns this: NULL
NULL
NULL   I removed the array() and replaced it with new

Comment: FYI, you seem to be passing the values to your Customer constructor in the wrong order.

Comment: @Patrick Q The values are now in the right order, but still NULL NULL NULL.

Comment: Please read ALL the comments

Comment: Can you update the question with your current code please? It's very hard to follow if we're trying to piece it together from comments.

Comment: `function __construct($name, $id,$email)` vs `\Customer($this->redis->hget($value,"name"),$this->redis->hget($value,"email"),$this->redis->hget($value,"id"))`.  Note where "email" and "id" are.  It really doesn't have anything to do with the specific problem you're having, but you definitely should be creating your object correctly if you want to get the desired results.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: You are STILL returning INSIDE the foreach loop and therefore only ONE Customer will be returned

Comment: You getting null because your function return only **1** object -> and in PHP, when using `foreach` loop on object you get his fields -> and the fields do **not** have the `getName` function

Comment: Problem has been solved. Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your Problem**: you do not return array of customer but only one. You getting null because your function return only **1** object -> and in PHP, when using `foreach` loop on object you get his fields -> and the fields do **not** have the `getName` function.

**Solution**: Init customer array, populate it and return from the function.

```
 public function getAllCustomers()
{
    $customers = $this->redis->keys("customer:*");
    $customersObjs = array();
    foreach ($customers as $value) {
        $customersObjs[] = new Customer($this->redis->hget($value,"name"),$this->redis->hget($value,"id"),$this->redis->hget($value,"email")));
    }
    return $customersObjs;
}
```

Now you have array of the `customersObjs` you can loop on with:

```
foreach ($customerController->getAllCustomers() as $customer) {
    echo $customer->getName();
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. @RiggsFolly This method is also returning inside the foreach loop and it is working.

Comment: "is also returning inside the foreach loop"  No, it definitely is not. Please take the time to review the difference between this and what you had. You might also want to review [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) for what exactly `return` does.

Comment: Sorry for that, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
public function getAllCustomers()
{
    $customers = $this->redis->keys("customer:*");
    $custumersArray = array();
    foreach ($customers as $value) {
        $custumersArray[] = \Customer($this->redis->hget($value,"name"),$this->redis->hget($value,"email"),$this->redis->hget($value,"id"));
    }
    return $custumersArray;
}
```

the problem was that you are returning a single array but not a array list.